# Display two different Grids in the same form not at the same time

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have two different Gridviews that I have to display in the same form but not at the same time. Display `Grid1` when the user presses `Button1` and `Grid2` when they press `Button2`.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a WinForms application then I suggest to put both grids on your form designer surface, with a minimum size to be operable, one of the two grids will have its Visible property set initially to False. Also put your buttons on the form inside a panel and dock the panel to the bottom of your form.

When the code enters the form constructor apply the Dock = DockStyle.Fill to both grids and change the Visible property of the two grids at the button click

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    grid1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    grid2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill   ' This has the Visible = False
End Sub

Public Sub button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
     grid1.Visible = False
     grid2.Visible = True

End

Public Sub button2_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
     grid1.Visible = True
     grid2.Visible = False
End
```

Comment: i did it but i have an error message: the method Grid1 is not implementes and  this is my code:                                                                                       Private Sub Génerer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Génerer.Click
        Dim frm As New Liste_Factures_search
        frm.Show()
        Grid1.visible = False
   GridF.Visible = True
        Generer_factures()
    End Sub

Comment: Grid1 and Grid2 are not methods they are a placeholders for your effective grid names. I don't know how do you have named these grids in your designer. Replace them with your effective name

Comment: in my designer i named these by Grid1 and GridF

Comment: In the New sub there is a call to InitializeComponent?

Comment: this is the Sub:    
    <Private Sub Génerer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Génerer.Click
        Dim frm As New Liste_Factures_search
        frm.Show()
        GridF.Visible = True
        Grid1.visible = False
        Generer_factures()
    End Sub>

Comment: but i have the same error message:  Variable objet ou variable d'un bloc With non définie. i m really blocked

Comment: It is not clear if GridF and Grid1 are controls on the _Liste_Factures_search_ or not

Comment: what do you mean by controls??? I know that GridF and Grid1 are present in  Liste_Factures_search design.

Comment: The code I have posted should go inside the _Liste_Factures_search.vb_ file. Controls are elements of User Interface like buttons, textboxes, labels, datagridview etc,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Change both gridviews visible property to false and change it to true when the button is clicked.